# How to use AtMega328P-PN

Tags: atmega328, bootloader

I am making an AC (the summer kind) control circuit with an AtMega328P chip. I bought the AtMega328P-PN instead of the P-PU. I followed the instructions on how to burn the bootloader, but nothing seems to work on the P-PN. I searched on Google for it and could find nothing anywhere.

Thanks in advance,

Iain

Comment: `I followed the instructions` -- *which* instructions? Did they also include instructions on setting the right fuses for your clock source?

Comment: And what do you mean `nothing seems to work`...? *What* doesn't work about it? Does the bootloader fail to flash? Does it flash but fail to be identified by avrdude? What...?

Answer (score 2):

The ATmega328P-PN differs from the ATmega328P-PU essentially only in being rated over a wider temperature range.

It is for all ordinary purposes a direct substitute for where an ATmega328P-PU could be used, and has the same signature word.

Whatever your actual problem is, it is elsewhere.

(The chips that *do* require some special accommodation if ordered are the ATmega328 *without* a "P" before the dash and the ATmega328PB)